# one url for all pages

Tags: plugins, permalinks, url-rewriting, home-url

Recently I just stocked over something which I can not fix or solve! I like to use a single url like [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) or [www.mywebsite.com/something](http://www.mywebsite.com/something) for all my pages. the reason is that I have a white label products but when a user click on the order, the url shows my reseller url which to many people looks fishy.

I appreciate any help

Comment: I'm guessing you have a WooCommerce store? So you either need to change the checkout process to use AJAX throughout and not ever reload the page - I don't know WooCommerce well so I don't know if that's possible or not - or you could maybe change the checkout process so when they click on the order it still shows an URL from the domain you were already on.

Comment: If all your pages have the same address, how will the site know which one to show the user? Perhaps I've misunderstood, your question doesn't contain much information. Use the ediit link under the tags to add more information and context about your situation and what you're using. Provide as much information as possible, this will help people understand your question and attract more answers